# Getting "404 - Not found" error with Wildfly and springboot

Tags: spring-boot, http-status-code-404, wildfly

Hello i am trying to learn wildfly and springboot with a very simple application using eclipse. 
The project name is springboot-test.
All the classes including the main method class are in the same package.

Main method class is called 'App' which has the following code:

```
 @SpringBootApplication
 @RestController
 public class App {

    @Autowired
    private Student student;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String sayHello()
    {
        return "hello from spring boot" + this.student.showAddress();
    }
}
```

Here are the server logs:

> 11:36:57,281 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/springboot-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT' for server 'default-server'
>
> 11:36:57,301 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "springboot-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name : "springboot-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")
>
> 11:36:57,408 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
>
> 11:36:57,411 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:8181/management
>
> 11:36:57,412 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:8181
>
> 11:36:57,412 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 11.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 3.0.8.Final) started in 11393ms - Started 504 of 732 services (353 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)

Url i am accessing is: **http://localhost:8080/springboot-test/index**

Comment: Does your project work when run as standalone (I mean, outside of Wildfly, using the default embedded Tomcat instance of a Spring Boot app) ?

Comment: Hello, yes it works fine with embedded tomcat. Then I am simply accessing the page with:
http://localhost:8080/index

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Think ,its same issue you are facing https://stackoverflow.com/a/50038209/1450401

Comment: @CharlesMorin I was facing the same issue , this 
 was my problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/50038209/1450401

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using wildfly for deployment , I'm hoping you are generating war file and server logs seems to support my statement

Do you have **SpringBootServletInitializer** class ??? if not that's the issue

You need something like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServletInitializer.class, args);
    }

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(ServletInitializer.class);
     }

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException{
    super.onStartup(servletContext);

     }
@RequestMapping("/index")
public String sayHello(){
        return "hello from spring boot" + this.student.showAddress();
    }
}
```

I' not sure is there any issue in annotating  `@SpringBootApplication`and `@RestController` in one class. But my suggestion is to keep it separate for maintenance

```
@RestController
public class Mycontroller{

  @RequestMapping("/index")
  public String sayHello(){
      return "hello from spring boot" + this.student.showAddress();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Server log says:

> 11:36:57,281 INFO [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService
>   Thread Pool -- 68) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context:
>   '/springboot-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT' for server 'default-server'

It should be accessible at:
http://localhost:8080/springboot-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/index

Configure your Maven file to use `<finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>` if you like to register your address.

Comment: Hello, so does that mean we have to build the project before deploying to the WildFly server?

Comment: Since WildFly is an application server: yes, normally you deploy packed applications, see: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/Application+deployment